# How to index a 3-D tensor with 2-D tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use a 2-D tensor to index a 3-D tensor in Tensorflow. For example, I have `x` of shape `[2, 3, 4]`:

```
[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
  [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

 [[12, 13, 14, 15],
  [16, 17, 18, 19],
  [20, 21, 22, 23]]]
```

and I want to index it with another tensor `y` of shape `[2, 3]`, where each element of `y` index the last dimension of `x`. For example, if we have `y` like:

```
[[0, 2, 3],
 [1, 0, 2]]
```

The output should of shape `[2, 3]`:

```
[[0, 6, 11],
 [13, 16, 22]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the indices using `tf.meshgrid` and then use `tf.gather_nd` to extract the elements:

```
# create a list of indices for except the last axis
idx_except_last = tf.meshgrid(*[tf.range(s) for s in x.shape[:-1]], indexing='ij')

# concatenate with last axis indices
idx = tf.stack(idx_except_last + [y], axis=-1)

# gather elements based on the indices
tf.gather_nd(x, idx).eval()

# array([[ 0,  6, 11],
#        [13, 16, 22]])
```

Comment: What if the shape of x is unknown? For example, the first dimension of x and y are computed in the runtime and I do not know the value during graph construction. `tf.range` function will fail if the parameter is `Dimension(None)`.

Comment: For dynamic shape, try `x.get_shape()` for `x.shape`.